# Why does strcat fail to concatenate two strings?

Tags: c, string, function

I need to convert a number into a string. I'm a dealer and distribute cards to players. The deck contains 40 cards. Four seeds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *convertNum(int a); //initialization function

void main(){
   char *car=convertNum(30);
   printf(" number to convert 30 : %s", car);
   getch();
}

char *convertNum(int a){
   char *seed, *value;
   switch ((a-1)/10){
      case 0: seed="C"; break;
      case 1: seed="Q"; break;
      case 2: seed="F"; break;
      case 3: seed="P"; break;
      default: seed="X"; break;
   }
   switch(a%10){
      case 0: value="10"; break;
      case 1: value="01"; break;
      case 2: value="02"; break;
      case 3: value="03"; break;
      case 4: value="04"; break;
      case 5: value="05"; break;
      case 6: value="06"; break;
      case 7: value="07"; break;
      case 8: value="08"; break;
      case 9: value="09"; break;
      default: value="XX"; break;
   }
   strcat(value, seed); /* ERROR: I need to concatenate the strings value and seed, but this isn't the right way */
   return value;
}
```

What can I do to concatenate the strings? `value` and `seed` are pointers.

Comment: You haven't allocated memory to any of pointer , concatenating them would cause error. First allocate sufficient memory and then concatenate.

Comment: You read the documentation on `strcat` and proceed from there.

Comment: In addition to not initializing the pointers or having them point at allocated memory, you can't return pointers to local data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function,you are assigning the pointers `seed` and `value` to string literals in the `switch` statements,however,what you need to do is allocate memory for these two pointers,copy strings to them using `strcpy()` or other standard library function,and concatenate at the end of the function.Make sure the allocated memory is big enough to hold both strings along with the `'\0'` character.Finally don't forget to free allocated memory when done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *convertNum(int a);

void main(){
   char *car=convertNum(30);
   printf("number to convert 30 : %s\n", car);
   free(car);
   getch();
}

char *convertNum(int a){
   char *seed = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char)), *value = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
   switch ((a-1)/10){
      case 0: strcpy(seed,"C"); break;
      case 1: strcpy(seed,"Q"); break;
      case 2: strcpy(seed,"F"); break;
      case 3: strcpy(seed,"P"); break;
      default: strcpy(seed,"X"); break;
   }
   switch(a%10){
      case 0: strcpy(value,"10"); break;
      case 1: strcpy(value,"01"); break;
      case 2: strcpy(value,"02"); break;
      case 3: strcpy(value,"03"); break;
      case 4: strcpy(value,"04"); break;
      case 5: strcpy(value,"05"); break;
      case 6: strcpy(value,"06"); break;
      case 7: strcpy(value,"07"); break;
      case 8: strcpy(value,"08"); break;
      case 9: strcpy(value,"09"); break;
      default:strcpy(value,"XX"); break;
  }
   strcat(value, seed);
   free(seed);
   return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.The pointers *value and *seed are uninitialized . They have no meomories. You need to initialize those pointers using malloc() or calloc() with some block of memory then it can hold values.

Hope this will work for you

Comment: This is not 100% correct: The pointers `value` and `seed` are directed to strings literals in the `switch` statements. So they point to some memory, but you are not allowed to write to that memory.

Comment: If a pointer is uninitialized , how can we prove that it is allocated memory but we are not authorised to write in that memory?

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing `value` and `seed` to string literals in your `switch` statements. You are not allowed to modify string literals with `strcat()`, because they are stored in read-only memory.

You could use [`malloc()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) in your `convertNum()` function to solve your problem. But then please don't forget to call [`free()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) when you no longer need a string. However, you can also provide a statically allocated array of characters from your `main()` function to the `convertNum()` function. This makes sense here, because your result strings will always have a fixed length of 3 characters:

```
void main(){
    // Allocate an array of four characters and initialize it with zeros.
    // You need 4 characters, because strings need to be zero terminated.
    char car[4] = {0};
    // Pass (a pointer to) the array to your covertNum() function.
    convertNum(30, car);
    printf(" number to convert 30 : %s", car);
    getch();
}
```

Then you have to modify your `convertNum()` function as follows:

```
void convertNum(int a, char* result){
    char *seed, *value;
    switch ((a-1)/10){
        [...]
    }
    switch(a%10){
        [...]
    }
    strcpy(result, value);  // Copy 'value' to the beginning of the 'result' array.
    strcat(result, seed);   // Append 'seed' to 'value'; 'result' becomes zero-terminated.
}
```

This gives the following output:

> number to convert 30 : 10F

In case you want your output to be `F10`, then you have to switch `value` and `seed` in the last two lines of the `convertNum()` function.